# Opacity of the button affects its "clickability"

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-zstack, swiftui-map

I've run into a very strange issue. I have a SwiftUI app (iOS) where I have a full-screen `ZStack`: inside, as a "bottom layer", I have a full-screen `Map`, and on top I have a button (it is `LocationButton` - but it doesn't really matter, the behaviour is the same with a regular `Button` too).

My button has an opacity modifier, which sets it to `0.5`, and a corresponding action. At this point, everything works: I can scroll the map, I can click the button - and the action will be executed.

However, as soon as I added `.onTapGesture` to the map - the button started to behave oddly. Only some clicks were propagated to it. It's almost like I had to hit a few specific pixels of the button to get its action executed.

I spent a couple of hours experimenting with the layout and different modifiers - nothing seemed to help. For example, I tried adding `.contentShape(Rectangle())` to the button - no luck. But, eventually, I noticed an interesting effect: if I remove the opacity from the button - it works again. Then I tried intermediate values for the opacity - it seems that the lower is the opacity (the more transparent is the button) - the more tricky it's to hit it with a tap (even though the size is not changed).

Can someone explain to me, why does opacity in this specific layout affects the "clickability" of the button? Because it doesn't affect it when I don't have `.onTapGesture` on my map - so I think it must be somehow related...

Comment: You likely are missing `contentShape(Rectangle())`. Does that change it?

Comment: I tried adding it when I was experimenting (I assume you meant adding it to the button?). It didn't help :( But I'll update the question.

Comment: This really needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is a certain point in opacity where the button, or any view, loses the ability to accept a tap, but this is around opacity of 0.01 I think.

Comment: The order with which you apply the modifiers might be important. I wuld suggest adding ```.contentShape``` _after_ ```.opacity```.